# Query for automatically refreshing a dynamic database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a database that is dynamic and new data inserted. I want a query for flushing out the old data and inserting the new data and this should be done automatically (without me manually refreshing the database table every time using the "Refresh" option. My database table is based on incoming of packets. I am also using JFreeChart to represent the dynamic data. Is there any way I could implement this with a query, using a trigger, stored procedure or a scheduled job? And I want this done only with queries and not in server-side.

Comment: you can create cronjob to do this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, since the implementation depends on from where and how you receive the data.

You mentioned that you would like to implement it using queries only, which implies you would prefer a mysql only solution. In this case use mysql's built-in [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) to execute queries according to a regular schedule.

If this does not meet your requirements, then you have to use a job scheduler offered by the server's operating system, such as cron or windows task scheduler.